# HTML form input control before form action tot php

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

How can I first check the input before "action=send.php" executes?

For example the borders get red when value is null.

```
<form action="send.php" onsubmit="CheckInput()">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
function CheckInput() {
    ...
}
</script>
```

So how it works? Does it first do the check and then "send.php" gets executed or does it execute "send.php" anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form onsubmit with php and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461855/form-onsubmit-with-php-and-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the Function gets executed before the post of the form.

If the javascript function returns false, the form won't get posted.
If the javascript function returns true, the form will get posted.

Comment: Yes that is exactly my question. I will test it asap.

Answer (score 0):

What happens depends on what the function `CheckInput()` returns -- it must return `false` to prevent the form from being submitted to "send.php".

Comment: You also have to change to `onsubmit="return CheckInput();"`